# Youtube launches in an appliaction when navigated to via WebView (AndroidStudio)

Tags: java, android, webview, youtube

I have a simple program that should load youtube website in a webView when the app launches, but the app simply open native Youtube appliacation instead, but I need it to open Youtube website in the webView.

I tried looking in the "attributes" section in webView settings, but couldn't find anything that could enforce websites like this to be opened in the webView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView web = findViewById(R.id.webV);
    web.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
}
```

I want the "www.youtube.com" website to be opened in my WebView app, not in the native Youtube app that currently opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this due to youtube video url is opened in browser and browser redirects it to native app

add following code

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

**UPDATE**

> When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView, the
>   default behavior is for Android to launch an application that handles
>   URLs. Usually, the default web browser opens and loads the destination
>   URL. However, you can override this behavior for your WebView, so
>   links open within your WebView. You can then allow the user to
>   navigate backward and forward through their web page history that’s
>   maintained by your WebView.
>
> To open links clicked by the user, simply provide a WebViewClient for
>   your WebView, using setWebViewClient().

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue, could you just clarify how exactly this piece of code prevents webiste like youtube from opening via app - what is the meaning of the code? thank you